# assembly BT sintax

Tags: assembly, x86, masm32

I'm getting

Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 6.14.8444
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1981-1997.  All rights reserved.

Assembling: E:\RaamSoft\SICBasm\EasyCode\TestIOsicb2.asm

---

ASCII build

---

E:\RaamSoft\SICBasm\EasyCode\TestIOsicb2.asm(117) : error A2070: invalid instruc
tion operands
E:\RaamSoft\SICBasm\EasyCode\TestIOsicb2.asm(118) : error A2006: undefined symbo
l : axe
E:\RaamSoft\SICBasm\EasyCode\TestIOsicb2.asm(119) : error A2006: undefined symbo
l : axe
E:\RaamSoft\SICBasm\EasyCode\TestIOsicb2.asm(120) : error A2006: undefined symbo
l : axe
E:\RaamSoft\SICBasm\EasyCode\TestIOsicb2.asm(121) : error A2006: undefined symbo
l : axe
E:\RaamSoft\SICBasm\EasyCode\TestIOsicb2.asm(123) : error A2006: undefined symbo
l : axe
E:\RaamSoft\SICBasm\EasyCode\TestIOsicb2.asm(125) : error A2006: undefined symbo
l : axe
E:\RaamSoft\SICBasm\EasyCode\TestIOsicb2.asm(132) : error A2006: undefined symbo
l : axe
_
Assembly Error
Press any key to continue . . .

These are statements 117 thru 134.

```
     bt   [esi + ebx + 4],   15    ; El año es impar? 
     mov   axe,    esi
     add   axe,    ebx
     add   axe,    4
     bt   [axe],   15              ; El año es impar?
     jc    skipdia                 ; Si, no puede ser bisiesto
     bt   [axe],   7               ; La decada es impar?
     jnc   TestMul4
     bt   [axe],   14              ; El año es 2 o 6?
     jnc   skipdia
   Pon29:  
     mov   ax,     3239h
     mov  [edi],   ax
     jmp      skipdia
   TestMul4:
     bt   [axe],   14              ; El año es 2 o 6?
     jc    skipdia                 ; Si, no puede ser bisiesto
     jmp   Pon29
```

What worries me is the syntax of BT, and for that of all instructions. I have not found a clear cut explanation to this. I'm shore it must be out there. I'm also interested in instruction timings having programmed in IBM /360 in BPS Assembly for IBM 1419 which has asynchronous processing of pocket selection with time constraints.

Comment: _"I'm sure it must be out there"_ Yes, it's called the [Intel Software Developer Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html)

Comment: There is no x86 register named `axe`.

Comment: Thank you, I'm new at PC assembly and a bit dyslexic. It should be eax.

Comment: The question still stands since it does not accept "bt [eax], 14", got around the problem putting both Bytes in Reg dx. However I will now have to take into cosideration that the order of the Bytes are inverted in Register.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the square brackets (and in the first instance, arrange for eax to hold the value you need to test in the register itself before you bit test).

[eax] = Access the *address* referenced by eax, not the *value* of eax.